# uppercase surname with apostrophe in php

Tags: php

I want to ensure all surnames are uppercased, so in php I use:

```
$surname = ucfirst(strtolower($dataField));
```

How do I ensure that any names such as O'Brien, don't result in O'brien

Comment: Most companies will either rely on human judgment regarding names, will transform it all into uppercase, or will just rely on the conventions of the customer who input their name.

Comment: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 1):

```
$surname = preg_replace('/\b(\w)(\w*)/', '\u$1\L$2', $surname);
```

The `\b` is a metacharacter that means "the border of a word." `\w` means any word character ([A-Za-z]). The `\u` in the replacement means "uppercase the first letter after." The `\L` means "lowercase until the end of the match."

This is by no means a complete solution. Computers are kind of dumb when it comes to human names.

[This is a great article on the subject.](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)